# Why different shapes of array can have those following calculation?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I dont know why the shapes of c,d,e,f are (3,4), how can a==b,a * b,a + b,a > b, be valid? Thank you!

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4]).reshape(1, -1) # "a" is a row vector
print(a)
b = np.array([1,3,6]).reshape(-1, 1) # "b" is a column vector
print(b)
c = (a == b)
d = (a * b)
e = (a + b)
f = (a > b)
print(f'c.shape is {c.shape}. d.shape is {d.shape}. e.shape is {e.shape}. f.shape is {f.shape}.')
```

[this is the running result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEekQ.png)
​

Comment: Read about [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/theory.broadcasting.html).

Comment: `a` is (1,4)` and `b` is (3,1); by broadcasting they produce (3,4) results.